# Error creating service account using Helm on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a service account using helm on Kubernetes as described here:

https://tutorials.kevashcraft.com/k8s/install-helm/

When I execute the following line:

kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'

I get an error:

Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string

Can someone give me some guidance as to what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"serviceAccount\":\"tiller\"}}}}"` i.e. using outer double-quotes and escaping the inner double-quotes. There's a [github issue](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/1273#issuecomment-323127597) where somebody hit the same error in a different context and was able to resolve it like this.

Edit: MrTouya determined that in this case what worked was `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"serviceAccount\":\"tiller\"}}}}'`

Comment: Hmm. I understand. I tried to execute the line you gave me and I still got an error: Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string. I will try a few other things as well since I understand what is going on. Keep in mind that I am executing this command in a VS Code terminal window on a Windows machine - if that helps. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ok. This worked.  kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"serviceAccount\":\"tiller\"}}}}'  I will give you credit for pointing me in the right direction! Thanks :-)

Comment: @MrTouya Cool, thanks and glad you got it sorted. Have put a note on the answer to make the solution easier to find.